# Adding Services to Controllers in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to identify if I understand some core concepts in AngularJS. If I have a line of code that says:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
```

and I change it to:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $myService) {
```

Is it correct to say that "$myService was injected into MyCtrl". Or is it more correct to say that "$myService is injected as a dependency of MyCtrl"? Or, should it be said some other way entirely?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct to say that you inject service in a controller as you would be using service methods in that controller, either as a data transfer across multiple controllers or by getting it via server.

It is recommended to inject service using this notation

```
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope','$myService',function($scope, $myService) {}]);
```

As when you minify your controller js then it will give no errors in this format.

Answer (score 1):

Either are fine.  In your example, myService was injected into MyCtrl as a dependency of MyCtrl.

One note, though.  You shouldn't name your services with a dollar sign at the beginning as that is reserved for providers within the Angular source code.

Instead, do:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, MyService) {
```

Answer (score 0):

A service is a way to maintain common state between several controllers, so yes, injecting a service into a controller is entirely correct.

[**Docs**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)